# Limit of sequence defined by a continuous distribution function

Tags: limits, probability-theory, probability-distributions, continuity

Let $F$ be a distribution function. Assume that $F$ is never equal to $1$. (**EDIT:** Assume also that $F$ is *not* an exponential distribution function; I forgot to mention this previously.) Fix a $d > 0$. We define a sequence of positive real numbers $(x_m)_{m\geq 1}$ by
$$x_m = \frac{1-F((m+1)d )}{1-F(md)}.$$

I want to show that $x_m \to 1$ for $m \to \infty$. In fact, I think this is true, but I am not entirely sure of it.

It is clear that $x_m$ is bounded, since $x_m \leq 1$ for all $m$, as any distribution function is non-decreasing. Therefore $\{ x_m \; | \; m \geq 1 \}$ has a supremum. Supposedly this supremum should be equal to $1$. However, I haven't been able to make this precise, nor to book further progress on proving this. Of course, the problem here is that both the enumerator as well as denominator converge to zero, which makes things more complicated.

Comment: The limit can't be $1$ in general, just take the exponential distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F$ be an exponential distribution, that is $1-F(x) = e^{\lambda x}$ for some $\lambda>0$ and all $x\geq 0$.

In that cas, as already said in a comment by @Michh, your limit is $e^{-\lambda d}$, and not $1$.

In the case where the tail function $1-F$ is [regularly varying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slowly_varying_function) , the limit would be $1$. For instance when $F$ is a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution) or a stable distribution of index $<2$. Those would all be examples of heavy-tailed distributions, unlike the distributions we are used to (Poisson, Normal, Exponential).

Comment: What if $F$ is not an exponential? I forgot to add that the given assumption is not the exponential distribution.

Comment: See my answer. It's not just the exponential that doesn't work. Most of the distributions we first learn about in probability theory wouldn't give a $1$ in your limit. The ones that would are necessarily *heavy-tailed*, which implies they are not very well behaved (for instance, they don't obey the CLT).